# Accept QueryString for Image delivered by Controller

Tags: image-scaling, imageresizer

I'm trying to make a controller that delivers a random background image. I have a MVC route from /random-background.jpg to /MyController/RandomBackground, and it's returns File(backgroundImage, "image/jpeg"). This is working fine.

I've disabled the 404 plugin for all QueryStrings that ends with random-image, so the image is showing up. However, it won't take any parameters, such as random-background.jpg?width=200. &format=jpg doesn't have any effect either.

How do I get ImageResizer to accept this for a "real image"? Do I have to use ImageResizer.ImageJob? If so, I would love an example I can understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageResizer V3 and earlier cannot 'post-process' the result of an MVC action or third-party HTTPHandler.

You will need to use one of the virtual providers plugins, use URL rewriting, or implement your own IVirtualImageProvider.

[See the best practices guide for an explanation of 'why'.](http://imageresizing.net/docs/best-practices)

Comment: I guess something like https://gist.github.com/benerdin/8187081 would work also - but you are saying that this is bad practice and that a plugin would be better? That one wouldn't save images using DiskCache. If I wrote a plugin I would like ImageResizer to work as usual with all my settings, without me not having to consider everything from 404, diskcache and such.

Comment: If you write a plugin, it should 'just work' with all the other plugins - 404, diskcache, etc.